# Stanford Parser: How to extract dependencies

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, stanford-parser

I would like to extract all of the dependencies in a sentence using Stanford parser. Consider the followoing code

```
        LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel();
        lp.setOptionFlags(new String[] { "-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories" });
        String[] sent = "There is a football on the grass pitch which is 50% white with a pressure flow of 1".split(" ");
        List<CoreLabel> rawWords = Sentence.toCoreLabelList(sent);
        Tree parse = lp.apply(rawWords);
        parse.pennPrint();
        System.out.println();

        TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
        GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
        GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
        List<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
        System.out.println(tdl);
        TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
        tp.printTree(parse);

        Collection<TypedDependency> td = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();
        //System.out.println(td);

        Object[] list = td.toArray();
        System.out.println(list.length);
        TypedDependency typedDependency;
        for (Object object : list) {
            typedDependency = (TypedDependency) object;
            System.out.println(
                    "Depdency Name " + typedDependency.dep().toString() + " :: " + typedDependency.reln());
            if (typedDependency.reln().getShortName().equals("something")) {
                // your code
            }
        }
```

so this allows me to see the dependencies as

```
Depdency Name There/EX :: expl
Depdency Name is/VBZ :: root
Depdency Name a/DT :: det
Depdency Name football/NN :: nsubj
Depdency Name on/IN :: case
Depdency Name the/DT :: det
Depdency Name grass/NN :: compound
Depdency Name pitch/NN :: nmod:on
Depdency Name which/WDT :: nsubj
Depdency Name is/VBZ :: cop
Depdency Name 50%/CD :: nummod
Depdency Name white/JJ :: amod
Depdency Name with/IN :: case
Depdency Name a/DT :: det
Depdency Name pressure/NN :: nmod:with
Depdency Name flow/NN :: acl:relcl
Depdency Name of/IN :: case
Depdency Name 1/CD :: nmod:of
```

now, when i visualize the same at http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

i see

[image]

How can i extract everything that is dependent on the `nsubj`? For instance in this case,

1. I want to know what the sunbject is. This is easy as i just look for the node name `nsubj`
2. Now i also want the following information

   - Where is the football ? `on the grass pitch`
   - Any other attributes of the football? `which is 50% white` and `pressure flow of 1`

How should i navigate the tree in order to extract these dependencies? Is there a way for me to start at the `nsubj` node and go to all the dependencies?

Comment: You'll want to read up on Semgrex which will allow you to find patterns in dependency trees.  The slides for Semgrex are available at this link: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex.shtml

Comment: Also first off you'll want to review this material on the basic API.  Once you build a Stanford CoreNLP pipeline and run on your text, you can use Semgrex on the SemanticGraph.  If you study this page you can see how to run a pipeline on text and access the SemanticGraph: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Comment: So first build a pipeline and annotate your text, and then secondly use Semgrex to find patterns in the SemanticGraph.

Comment: You will mainly want to look over the power point slides for Semgrex at this location: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/Semgrex.ppt

Comment: In that power point there is sample code at the end.